# Use the Nth underscore from the right as the separator to split a column into two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` as follows:

```
    id          value_type_and_model_name
0    1                       actual_value
1    2             fitted_value_RUT_ARIMA
2    3       fitted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA
3    4       fitted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA
4    5          predicted_value_RUT_ARIMA
5    6    predicted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA
6    7    predicted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA
7    8                fitted_value_RUT_ES
8    9          fitted_lower_value_RUT_ES
9   10          fitted_upper_value_RUT_ES
10  11             predicted_value_RUT_ES
11  12       predicted_lower_value_RUT_ES
12  13       predicted_upper_value_RUT_ES
13  14           fitted_value_RUT_SARIMAX
14  15     fitted_lower_value_RUT_SARIMAX
15  16     fitted_upper_value_RUT_SARIMAX
16  17        predicted_value_RUT_SARIMAX
17  18  predicted_lower_value_RUT_SARIMAX
18  19  predicted_upper_value_RUT_SARIMAX
```

I need to split `value_type_and_model_name` column (except `'actual_value'` in this column) into two columns: `value_type` and `model_name` using **the second underscore from the right** as the delimiter.
The expected result is as follows:

```
    id             value_type   model_name
0    1           actual_value          NaN
1    2           fitted_value    RUT_ARIMA
2    3     fitted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
3    4     fitted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
4    5        predicted_value    RUT_ARIMA
5    6  predicted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
6    7  predicted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
7    8           fitted_value        UT_ES
8    9     fitted_lower_value        UT_ES
9   10     fitted_upper_value        UT_ES
10  11        predicted_value        UT_ES
11  12  predicted_lower_value        UT_ES
12  13  predicted_upper_value        UT_ES
13  14           fitted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
14  15     fitted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
15  16     fitted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
16  17        predicted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
17  18  predicted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
18  19  predicted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
```

How to achieve this? Thanks. I try with code: `df['value_type_and_model_name'].str.rsplit('_', n=2, expand=True)`, but it's not working out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you "only" have one underscore in the second chunk, the easiest is to craft a regex for that specific case:

```
out = (df['value_type_and_model_name']
       .str.extract(r'(?P<value_type>.*)_(?P<model_name>[^_]*_[^_]*)$')
       .fillna({'value_type': df['value_type_and_model_name']})
      )
```

[regex demo (extract)](https://regex101.com/r/3gRLXW/1)

Output:

```
               value_type   model_name
0            actual_value          NaN
1            fitted_value    RUT_ARIMA
2      fitted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
3      fitted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
4         predicted_value    RUT_ARIMA
5   predicted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
6   predicted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
7            fitted_value       RUT_ES
8      fitted_lower_value       RUT_ES
9      fitted_upper_value       RUT_ES
10        predicted_value       RUT_ES
11  predicted_lower_value       RUT_ES
12  predicted_upper_value       RUT_ES
13           fitted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
14     fitted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
15     fitted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
16        predicted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
17  predicted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
18  predicted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
```

If you really want to [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['value_type_and_model_name'].str.split('_(?=[^_]*_[^_]*$)', expand=True)
```

[regex demo (split)](https://regex101.com/r/lS25TB/1)

If you want, you can assign to the original dataframe:

```
s = df.pop('value_type_and_model_name')
df[['value_type', 'model_name']] = (s.str.extract(r'(.*)_([^_]*_[^_]*)$')
                                     .fillna({0: s})
                                   )
```

Output:

```
    id             value_type        model
0    1           actual_value          NaN
1    2           fitted_value    RUT_ARIMA
2    3     fitted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
3    4     fitted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
4    5        predicted_value    RUT_ARIMA
5    6  predicted_lower_value    RUT_ARIMA
6    7  predicted_upper_value    RUT_ARIMA
7    8           fitted_value       RUT_ES
8    9     fitted_lower_value       RUT_ES
9   10     fitted_upper_value       RUT_ES
10  11        predicted_value       RUT_ES
11  12  predicted_lower_value       RUT_ES
12  13  predicted_upper_value       RUT_ES
13  14           fitted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
14  15     fitted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
15  16     fitted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
16  17        predicted_value  RUT_SARIMAX
17  18  predicted_lower_value  RUT_SARIMAX
18  19  predicted_upper_value  RUT_SARIMAX
```

Comment: Many thanks, except `actual_value` in `value_type` column seems becoming `NaN`s.

Comment: @ahbon it's because, technically, there is nothing to split/extract, but you can `fillna` with the original column. Let me update

Comment: I added a variant with `split`, which it actually not so bad

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'value_type_and_model_name': ['actual_value', 'fitted_value_RUT_ARIMA', 'fitted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA', 'fitted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA', 'predicted_value_RUT_ARIMA', 'predicted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA', 'fitted_value_RUT_ES', 'fitted_lower_value_RUT_ES', 'fitted_upper_value_RUT_ES', 'predicted_value_RUT_ES']})

"""
print(df)
   id        value_type_and_model_name
0   1                     actual_value
1   2           fitted_value_RUT_ARIMA
2   3     fitted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA
3   4     fitted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA
4   5        predicted_value_RUT_ARIMA
5   6  predicted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA
6   7              fitted_value_RUT_ES
7   8        fitted_lower_value_RUT_ES
8   9        fitted_upper_value_RUT_ES
9  10           predicted_value_RUT_ES
"""

def split_col(row):
    if row['value_type_and_model_name'] == 'actual_value' :
        aa = pd.Series(['actual_value',None])
        return aa
    else :
        parts = row['value_type_and_model_name'].rsplit('_',2)
        #join the remaining parts 
        bb = pd.Series([parts[0],'_'.join(parts[1:])])
        return bb
    
df[['value_type', 'model_name']] = df.agg(split_col,axis=1)
"""print(df)  

   id        value_type_and_model_name             value_type model_name
0   1                     actual_value           actual_value       None
1   2           fitted_value_RUT_ARIMA           fitted_value  RUT_ARIMA
2   3     fitted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA     fitted_lower_value  RUT_ARIMA
3   4     fitted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA     fitted_upper_value  RUT_ARIMA
4   5        predicted_value_RUT_ARIMA        predicted_value  RUT_ARIMA
5   6  predicted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA  predicted_lower_value  RUT_ARIMA
6   7              fitted_value_RUT_ES           fitted_value     RUT_ES
7   8        fitted_lower_value_RUT_ES     fitted_lower_value     RUT_ES
8   9        fitted_upper_value_RUT_ES     fitted_upper_value     RUT_ES
9  10           predicted_value_RUT_ES        predicted_value     RUT_ES
"""  


def split_col_regex(row):
  match = re.match(r"(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)", row['value_type_and_model_name'])
  if match:
    return pd.Series([match.group(1) + '_' + match.group(2), match.group(3)])
  else:
    return pd.Series(['actual_value', None])

df[['value_type1', 'model_name1']] = df.agg(split_col_regex,axis=1)

"""print(df.to_string()) 
  id        value_type_and_model_name             value_type model_name      value_type1      model_name1
0   1                     actual_value           actual_value       None     actual_value             None
1   2           fitted_value_RUT_ARIMA           fitted_value  RUT_ARIMA     fitted_value        RUT_ARIMA
2   3     fitted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA     fitted_lower_value  RUT_ARIMA     fitted_lower  value_RUT_ARIMA
3   4     fitted_upper_value_RUT_ARIMA     fitted_upper_value  RUT_ARIMA     fitted_upper  value_RUT_ARIMA
4   5        predicted_value_RUT_ARIMA        predicted_value  RUT_ARIMA  predicted_value        RUT_ARIMA
5   6  predicted_lower_value_RUT_ARIMA  predicted_lower_value  RUT_ARIMA  predicted_lower  value_RUT_ARIMA
6   7              fitted_value_RUT_ES           fitted_value     RUT_ES     fitted_value           RUT_ES
7   8        fitted_lower_value_RUT_ES     fitted_lower_value     RUT_ES     fitted_lower     value_RUT_ES
8   9        fitted_upper_value_RUT_ES     fitted_upper_value     RUT_ES     fitted_upper     value_RUT_ES
9  10           predicted_value_RUT_ES        predicted_value     RUT_ES  predicted_value           RUT_ES
"""
```